# Properly closing file of a gstreamer pipeline used in an OpenCV VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I'm reading a camera in a GStreamer pipeline on an NVidia TX2. I want the output to be h264 encoded and written to a file. Next to that, I want to have the frames available in OpenCV for further processing.

To do this I made the following pipeline that works using gst-launch:

```
gst-launch-1.0 nvcamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! \
'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1920, height=(int)1280, 
format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! tee name=t \
t. ! queue! omxh264enc ! 'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream' ! \
h264parse ! qtmux ! \
filesink location=test.mov \
t. ! queue! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw ! xvimagesink -e
```

This all works and there are no issues with this pipeline. It shows the frames on screen (this part will be replaced by an appsink in OpenCV) and a moviefile is created that can be played.

Please note the "-e" at the end of of the command. To stop recording I press ctrl-C. If I leave the "-e" out, I get a corrupt moviefile that is not playable. This also makes sense when checking the man-page for gst-launch-1.0, since it mentions specifically this case.

No when I translate this to OpenCV in Python I get this:

```py
import cv2

pipeline = ("nvcamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! "
        "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)640, height=(int)360, format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! tee name=t "
        "t. ! queue! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream ! "
        "h264parse ! qtmux ! "
        "filesink location=test.mov "
        "t. ! queue! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! "
        "videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink")


vc1 = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
while(True):
    _, vc1_f = vc1.read()

    cv2.imshow('vc1', vc1_f)
    if not cv2.waitKey(1) == -1:
        break

vc1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This also runs fine without any errors, the only thing that happens is that I end up with a corrupt movie file on exit. Exactly the same as when leaving out the "-e" option in the gst-launch version.

In all of this I realise I'm misusing the VideoCapture a bit, because that normally isn't used to write files, but only to get frames into OpenCV through the appsink element. Here, however, it is also used to write a file directly by using the gstreamer pipeline.

I can of course create a separate pipeline:

```
"appsrc ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=test.mov "
```

and feed back the frames I get in OpenCV into that by using a VideoWriter (I tested that and it works properly) but that creates some overhead, so I would prefer to not have to do this and keep it clean and stick to my one VideoCapture pipeline.

So basically my question is: is it possible what I want to do here? Or am I just abusing VideoCapture too much? I.e. is there a Python OpenCV equivalent to the gst-launch "-e" option for a VideoCapture, because VideoCapture::release() doesn't do the job.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Didn't find a proper solution (OpenCV forum [confirmed](http://answers.opencv.org/question/211220/writing-file-from-gstreamer-pipleine-in-a-videocapture-on-the-tx2/) it doesn't exist), but decided to only save the H264 stream and leave the muxing out of the pipeline and do that afterwards separately using ffmpeg. The H264 stream doesn't care about the unclean shutdown.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the camera id to `VideoCapture` without the Gstreamer pipeline, create a `VideoWriter` object with just the encoding part of the Gstreamer pipeline and pass the captured frame to it. I am guessing you're using Nvidia's proprietary Gstreamer plugins for hardware acceleration.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, I'll give that a try see how it works out! Thanks!

Comment: Seems like when opening a without a Gstreamer pipline (i.e. VideCapture(0)), OpenCV also opens a gstreamer pipeline in the background...

Comment: On a normal linux distribution, opencv uses V4L2 API to access the cameras. Do you have it installed? What is the output of `cv2.getBuildInformation`?

Comment: Didn't look into this any further. For now I solved it differently. instead of muxing in the gstreamer pipeline I decided to only save the H264 stream and do the muxing afterwards separately (using ffmpeg). The h264 stream doesn't care about the unclean cutoff.